# Perl Script in batch

Tags: regex, perl, batch-file

I got a shell script an need to "convert" it to a batch file!

```
SET LOADERMID=app\run
##### SHELL PART #####
cd /d %BASEDIR%
LOADERMID=${LOADERMID//\//\\\/}
# Copy & minify index.html to dist
cat "$SRCDIR/index.html" | tr '\n' ' ' | \
perl -pe "
  s/<\!--.*?-->//g;                          # Strip comments
  s/isDebug: *1/deps:['$LOADERMID']/;        # Remove isDebug, add deps
  s/<script src=\"$LOADERMID.*?\/script>//;  # Remove script app/run
  s/\s+/ /g;                # Collapse white-space" > "$DISTDIR/index.html"
echo "Build complete"
######## SHELL PART END ##########
```

I got the most of it working expect the following part that copies a file to another directory and does some regex/replacing stuff.

Now I don´t know how to do it in a batch file.

- Is it possible to call perl in batch?
- Is it possible to do that perl code in a batch file?

Thanks for help!

Comment: do you have Perl installed? And what kind of perl? The part of Wscript exe provided by microsoft or some other? Is the PERL.EXS in the `%PATH%`

Comment: A probably easier alternative is just to do the whole thing in Perl.

Comment: And what exactly do you want? To embed a perl code in batch or to rewrite the perl code in batch (rather pretty hard) ?

Comment: install [Perl for Windows](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) and run the interpreter with a Perl script.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself needing to run bash scripts in a windows environment, you could also try [MinGW and MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/).  MSYS, in particular, gives you a nice unixy command line environment that is useful for doing real work.